# C++11 delay the execution of thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'd like to create some threads (with c++11) and collect them in a 'vector'. Then I'd like to fire them up, not immediately upon construction of the associated thread object, but after a specified time. And this is my problem, how can I delay the execution of thread?

It is possible to do something like that? I appreciate any hints.

Comment: The thread function can wait for something to happen

Comment: So don't construct them until you want them to start.

Comment: I'd let each thread wait for a [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and when ready simply `notify_all`...

Comment: When you say "delay", do you mean for a specified time interval after creation?  Or to an absolute time value?   Or until some other condition is met?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to create some threads (with c++11) and collect them in a 'vector'. Then I'd like to fire them up, not immediately upon construction of the associated thread object

You can default construct the `std::thread` objects:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads(some_number);
```

> but after specified time

You can sleep for some time:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(some_time);
```

Once you're ready to start the execution, create a thread with a function and assign the ones in the vector:

```
threads[i] = std::thread(some_callable);
```

---

That said, creating the empty `std::thread` objects doesn't necessarily make a lot of sense since you could easily delay creating them until you actually want to execute something.

This approach does make sense when you want to use a constant length array of threads instead of a vector.

Comment: The default constructor does not actually create a thread.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, Chalk it up to the fundamental weirdness of C++'s value-oriented semantics. You can't have a variable of type `std::thread` without the variable having a "value." If you need the variable to exist before the thread exists, then there is no other way to do it except what eerorika said: Initialize it with the default "value" (which does not actually represent any OS thread), and then later assign it a new "value" that does represent a thread.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I know that. I meant that it doesn't create an actual thread even though it creates an instance of `std::thread`. OP appears to want to create a suspended thread.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, Sorry, I guess I should not have addressed my comment to you, but I wanted any beginners who read this answer and comments to understand _why_ the default constructor does not actually create a thread.

Answer (score 0):

My contribution is to provide you a simple working code as all the explanations were already provided by @eerorika perfectly. Please, feel free to look ak the comments within the code

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

/**
* action:
* @param: wait : duration of wating time before launchin an action
*         index: index of the thread
**/
void action(int wait, int index)
{
    // compute current time
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    // and display it
    std::string mytime(std::asctime(std::localtime(&result)));
    // only remove the end of line char from the time
    mytime.pop_back();
    std::cout << "Time is "<< mytime << " Create thread "<< index << " and wait " << (int) (wait/1000) << " seconds "<< std::endl;

    // force the thread to wait for the provided amount of time
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(wait));
    // re-compute current time
    std::time_t result2 = std::time(nullptr);
    mytime=std::asctime(std::localtime(&result2));
    mytime.pop_back();
    // and display it
    std::cout << "launch action "<< index << " "<< mytime << " after "<< (int)(wait/1000) << " seconds" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // a vector composed of 3 threads
    std::vector<std::thread> vecOfThreads(3);
    vecOfThreads[0]=std::thread(action,5000, 0);
    //sleep 15 ms to give the first thread to display his starting message
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(15));
    // create a thread and provide its runnable (function) and the two arguments of the function
    // and assign it to an element of your vector
    vecOfThreads[1]=std::thread(action,10000, 1);
    //sleep 15 ms to give the first thread to display his starting message
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(15));

    vecOfThreads[2]=std::thread(action,15000, 2);
    //sleep 15 ms to give the first thread to display his starting message
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(15));

    //waiting for the end of each thread
    vecOfThreads[0].join();
    vecOfThreads[1].join();
    vecOfThreads[2].join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) is for such purposes.

```
// Enable lazy and asynchronous evaluation of func(x, y) on a new thread.
auto a = std::async(std::launch::deferred | std::launch::async, &func, x, y);

// Do what you need.

// It is time to execute func(x, y), wait_for returns immediately without
// waiting regardless of timeout_duration value.
a.wait_for(0s);

// Do other work you need.

// Get the result, wait for a until it is finished if needed.
auto r = a.get();
```